# Coherent explanation of kalemia's effect on membrane potential

Tags: electrolytes

I've been looking for a good explanation of how plasmatic kalemia affects resting membrane potential, but I think I need some help. The intracellular side of the membrane is negatively charged, so naively, increasing blood kalemia (a positive ion) should increase that potential difference. However, that is not the case, it instead reduces the potential difference...

Other considerations:

- Na-K ATPase activity should increase in hyperkalemia (more K+ is available to bring into the cell), however that cannot be the main explanation, as that also goes in the wrong direction, creating a net electric current out of the cell...
- Ok, this should increase intracellular K+ even more, leading to a bigger K+ differential than usual. This is the only effect I could find which goes in the right direction to explain the reduced potential difference. However, one of the treatments for the effects of hyperkalemia (which I think implies restoring normal potential difference) is to use insulin to drive more K+ into the cells... which would instead further reduce it if higher intracellular K+ were the main reason for the decreased potential...

I know there are a bunch more ion channels and exchangers, but I don't know what their net effect is. I also know that intracellular K+ is not uniformly distributed and there are transporters there too. So these are probably part of what I'm missing...

Comment: I would upvote this question if it included a link or two supporting its main factual assertions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The physiological concentrations for K<sup>+</sup> is ~120mmol intracellularly and ~4mmol extracellularly. This means that you have a large driving force (1:30 extra vs intracellular) of positive charge to the outside of the cell, creating a negative potential across the cell membrane. Using the Nernst equation, you can calculate that this equilibrium potential of K<sup>+</sup> is somewhere around -90mV (`-60*log10(4/120)`).

If the blood potassium concentration (which is similar to the extracellular potassium concentration) increases from ~4mmol to ~6mmol, the ratio of extra vs intracellular decreases to around 1:20 and accordingly the equilibrium potential of K<sup>+</sup> is now somewhere around -80mV (`-60*log10(6/120)`). This means that - all things else being equal - the cell depolarises and is easier to excite<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>:You can calculate the membrane potential of a cell with the [Goldman-Hodgkin-Katz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_equation) equation, which basically is the sum of all equilibrium potentials times membrane conductance of all ions. Because cells are mostly permeable for potassium ions, the membrane potential very closely follows the equilibrium potential for potassium ions:

[image]

where P<sub>k</sub> is the membrane conductance, and [X]<sub>in</sub> is the intracellular ion concentration and [X]<sub>out</sub> is the extracellular concentration.

Comment: I get that the math kinda checks out, but that model is for ions that can cross the membrane freely and are driven only by their electrochemical gradient. If that were realistic, we'd have a gradient of 0 and the concentrations of everything would be the same inside and out... In terms of cell mechanisms, am I to understand that the intracellular K+ is tightly regulated at about 120mmol and that the cell manipulates the potential gradient to keep it there despite the increase in extracellular K+?

Comment: To keep the same equilibrium potential of ~-90mV, the cell would need to increase the intracellular K+ concentration from 120mmol to 180mmol, aka a 50% increase. This is not possible/viable. You can't get much potassium from outside to inside (there's only 2mmol more in the extracellular fluid), and halfing the cell volume to get to the same concentration is also no option. So it doesn't even need to be tightly regulated it needs to be just barely regulated :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess that mostly makes sense. I'd still be curious to know what actually happens to the intracellular K+ concentration during episodes of hyper/hypokalemia (a quick search didn't reveal any such experiments).

Comment: @Alexbib Haven‘t found anything either. It’s a good question but I presume that it is buffered quite well and does not change much - during non-letal hyper/hypokalemias the membrane potential also does not depolarise drastically, but rather small changes can already lead to arrhythmia. But this is just my educated guess, haven’t found anything in the literature